# Creating a new Folder with given path

Tags: python, tree-structure

I'm wondering if any of you have created a function to create a folder within a given path.

For Example: 
NewFolder = ['/projects/Resources/backup_Folder']

Comment: what do you want exacly? and maybe you can have a look into the module os.path.

Answer (score 19):

Use the `os` library, specifically `os.mkdir()`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir

For example,

```
path = "/usr/temp/foo"
os.mkdir(path)
```

If the intermediate folders don't exists, use `os.makedirs` as per Peter Wood's comment

```
path = "/newfolder1/newfolder2/foo"
os.mkdir(path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adam! It took me some time to understand what I was doing. I'm new to programming less than a year. landed an internship with a data science team. So this is all a learning experience for me. You were able to solve my issue.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your internship

Comment: This won't work if intermediate directories don't exist (e.g. if `/usr/temp` doesn't exist). You need [**`os.makedirs`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)